# Is it possible to use speech recognition in a SpriteKit app using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit to build an app.  The other functionality of the Scene is all done through SpriteKit.  I want to add speech recognition to the scene so that when the user touches the microphone button node, the words they say are matched against the correct word they needed to say to move on.  Is this possible on SpriteKit?  The code below is the function I am using but it is not causing anything to happen.

```
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        self.sendAlert(message: "There has been an audio engine error.")
        return print(error)
    }
    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        self.sendAlert(message: "Speech recognition is not supported for your current locale.")
        return
    }
    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        self.sendAlert(message: "Speech recognition is not currently available. Check back at a later time.")
        // Recognizer is not available right now
        return
    }
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
        if let result = result {

            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.labelNode.text = bestString

            var lastString: String = ""
            for segment in result.bestTranscription.segments {
                let indexTo = bestString.index(bestString.startIndex, offsetBy: segment.substringRange.location)
                lastString = bestString.substring(from: indexTo)
            }
            self.checkPhrase(resultString: lastString)
        } else if let error = error {
            self.sendAlert(message: "There has been a speech recognition error.")
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Below is the code I am using for when the mic node gets touched and nothing happens when I run it:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)


    if micButton.contains(location) {
        if isRecording == true {
            audioEngine.stop()
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            isRecording = false
        } else {
            self.recordAndRecognizeSpeech()
            isRecording = true
        }


    }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: I can´t get the code to ask for permission to use the microphone in Spritekit, but it works when I used almost the same exact code on UIKit.  Are there major differences between the two for getting voice recognition to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instance method **requestRecordPermission(_:)** to request the user’s permission for audio recording.

Try something like:

```
if (session.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")){
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
        if granted {
            println("granted")
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
            session.setActive(true, error: nil)
            self.recorder ()
        }else{
            println("not granted")
        }
    })
}   session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
        session.setActive(true, error: nil)
            self.recorder ()
        } else{
            println("not granted")
        }
     })
}
```